# Generic operator== for non-pod objects

Tags: c++

While doing some unit tests I want to be able to compare some pretty simple structs (they contain only public data members). I could write a `operator==` for all of them separately but it would be cumbersome and repetitive. So I decided to try to do this in a generic way. Yet there is a problem - some of them are not POD as some of their fields have non-POD type, let's say a `std::list` for an example.

```
struct NonPod {
    std::list<int> lst;
};

struct NonPod2 {
    std::list<NonPod> lst;
};

template<class T>
bool operator==(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    //what should I put here to make it work safely 
    //to compare NonPod with other NonPod
    //ant NonPod2 with other NonPod2
}
```

AFAIK, to compare POD safely I could just use `std::memcmp` and it would be all fine. Is it possible to do generic `operator==` for non-POD types as well? If so, how?

Comment: please be more specific, e.g. show examples of what you want to compare.

Comment: FWIW, C++20 will allows you to do `auto operator<=>(const class_name&) const = default;` to get all of the comparison operators defined for you type.

Comment: Why don't you use the equality operator, ==, for the comparison?

Comment: @NathanOliver that's not what I am asking. I just want to have generic `operator==` for any struct

Comment: what would be the semantic of comparing `NonPod` and `NonPod2`? should it just be `false`?

Comment: So you want to compare any type `T` to any type `U`?  What would you consider equal?  You can have two objects with the same binary value but not be the same.

Comment: @NathanOliver no, I just want to be able to compare two structs of the same type in generic manner, without boilerplate code. I think signature of `operator==` in example tellss it without a doubt

Comment: I doubt that there is a way _to compare two structs of the same type in generic manner_. It might be your intention to do it comparing member var. for member var. However, there might be `struct`s where this doesn't make sense. Consider that a struct may contain administrative data which should be left out in such a comparison.

Comment: @Scheff I know, yet it would make sense for some of them (for example the ones which are just bags of data) and that's what I am asking -  to compare member var for member var

Comment: And, btw. comparing POD with `std::memcmp()` doesn't sound very clever to me. I'm quite sure that `operator==()` is much more efficient than `memcmp()` for most primitive types. Comparison of two `int`s might result in a comparison of two register values and I strongly believe this cannot be provided by `memcmp()`.

Comment: @Scheff true, but writing `operator==` for every bag of data is just waste of time and energy which can be put into more productive things

Comment: @Scheff This is for unit tests.  Most of the "bags of data" will need sensible names for actual use in the code.

Comment: Would something like this help? https://github.com/cbeck88/visit_struct  You have to provide an extra declaration about what the fields are, but that's probably best c++ can do until it gets real reflection support.

Comment: Using `memcmp` for a POD will also compare the (indeterminate) contents of padding, which you definitely don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way to do this in C++17 (or earlier).  C++20 will allow you to add:

```
auto operator<=>(const class_name&) const = default;
```

to each class. This will give you all the comparison operators defined in the obvious way.

If the classes are being created by a code generator, then adding a comparison function should be easy.

Comment: I guess getting it in cpp17 is better than nothing ;)

Comment: @bartop cpp20 I'm afraid.

Comment: @MartinBonner: You should be advised that if all you want is equality comparison, you will be able to do `auto operator==(const class_name&) const = default;`.